# map() in node.js, async vs sync？

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a segment code like below running in Node.js. And I find it will always goes to else condiction, howerver with masterData is not null.

```
getOperationDetails(req, res) {
   let sql = 'select a.*, b.s*';
       sql += ` from ${paymentSheet} a left join ${paymentHisSheet} b on a.id= b.source_id `;
       sql += ' where a.id=? ';
   func.connPool(sql, id, (err, rows, field) => {
       if (err) {
         res.json({ code: 400, message: err })
       } else {
         let masterData = [];
         let details = rows.map((row, idx) => {
          if (idx === 0) {
            masterData.push({
              id: row.id,
              name: row.name
            });
          }
          return {
            operator: row.operator_info,
            comments: row.cmt,
            status: row.sta
          }
         })
        if (masterData.length > 0 ) { 
          masterData[0].details = details;
        } else {
          console.log(sql);
          console.log(id);
          console.log('=======================');
          console.log(masterData);
        }
        res.json({ code: 200, message: 'ok', data: masterData })
      }
   })
```

For example, the console will show like below. Obviously masterData has value. It means 'if' condiction run before map(). Do I have to use async to wait the map() handle the data over?

```
allConnections:2
select a.*, b.* from payment a left join history b on a.id= b.source_id  where a.id=? 
83e588cd-9b4b-4592-ac7f-529bfaa9b231
=======================
allConnections:2
allConnections:2
[
   {
     id: '83e588cd-9b4b-4592-ac7f-529bfaa9b231',
     name: 'Jeff'
    }
 ]
```

My anaysis:

the rows from database should like below

```
83e588cd-9b4b-4592-ac7f-529bfaa9b231', 'Jeff', 'Operator Peter', 'OK', 0
83e588cd-9b4b-4592-ac7f-529bfaa9b231', 'Jeff', 'Operator Mary', 'NO', 1
83e588cd-9b4b-4592-ac7f-529bfaa9b231', 'Jeff', 'Operator Jet', 'OK', 2
```

or like below, means no details

```
83e588cd-9b4b-4592-ac7f-529bfaa9b231', 'Jeff', null, null, null
```

That is why I use masterData to separate. I think push() should not be taken out the map(), becasue rows maybe return nothing. Will it be like map() is over and push() is still running?

====  P.S. func.connPool====

```
let mysql = require('mysql');
let db = require('../configs/db');
let pool = mysql.createPool(db);

module.exports = {
  connPool (sql, val, cb) {
      pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Connection Error:' + err);
          cb(err, null, null);
        } else {
          console.log('allConnections:' + pool._allConnections.length);
          let q = conn.query(sql, val, (err, rows,fields) => {
          pool.releaseConnection(conn);
          if (err) {
            console.log('Query:' + sql + ' error:' + err);
          }
          cb(err, rows, fields);
        });
      }
    });
  },
```

Comment: there's nothing asynchronous happening inside .map so ... no

Comment: im crazy about why it will go to else branch. I got the rows result from database and try to separate the master data the deatils data.

Comment: `map` is synchronous and don't see async calls in your code above, there must be something missing in the surrounding code?

Comment: `rows` is probably an empty array

Comment: Try console.log(JSON.stringify(masterData)) rather than logging the object itself. You will no doubt find masterData to be empty at that point. It's a trap for the unwary what the logged value of an object will change as the object changes.

Comment: I post the full method, rows is not empty. And the question is, sometimes, just sometims it will go to else branch.....mad...

Comment: "Will it be like map() is over and push() is still running?" Hell no. If you are entering the else section it is because masterData is empty, and no other reason. Put in more logs to follow your program state - and don't log the objects directly, use JSON.stringify so you see the objects as they were, not as they are.

Answer (score 1):

What I suspected is that the `push` operation is somehow delay because of some code that is not shown here (I am not certain yet).

I ran the following code so many times, I still could not reproduce your problem.

```js
var rows = [
    {
        id: "123",
        name: "test",
    },
    {
        id: "123",
        name: "test",
    },
    {
        id: "123",
        name: "test",
    },
]

let masterData = [];
let details = rows.map((row, idx) => {
    if (idx === 0) {
      masterData.push({
        id: row.id,
        name: row.name
      });
    }
    return {
      id: row.id,
      name: row.name,
    }
})
if (masterData.length > 0 ) {
    console.log("in");
} else {
    console.log(masterData);
    console.log('=======================');
}
```

Could you try whether it goes to `else` or not for this code.

Comment: @Ian Was `rows` passed as list type? Could you provide the code for `func.connPool`?

Comment: Chindanonda, iv tried, and the console shows 'in'...the logic is right. Anyway, I try to take push() out map() to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

From this piece of code you are pushing to MasterData only the first row.id and row.name.

(  that is specified in the if conditional for just the first index `idx === 0` )

So if thats the case you don't need to have this push thing inside the map.

You can take that out of the map and leave the iterator to create only the details array.

You can go with:

```
 let details = rows.map(row => ({
     operator: row.operator_info,
     comments: row.cmt,
     status: row.sta
     })
  );


let masterData = [{ id: rows[0].id, name: rows[0].name, details }]
```

Comment: Good point, though you'd need to check rows has length > 0 first.